# Is there a way to force a single frame update before rendering (as animation frame)?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm having issues with my complex armature. It's caused by some drivers being calculated before constraints, some after. There are no circular dependencies, but for example there are drivers depending on bone's Y scale, while the bone uses "Stretch To" constraint. When I change frame in viewport, some drivers only update a fraction of a second later, when the frame preview updates again. This is a no-issue for rendering stills, but when I render animations, some drivers lag 1 frame behind as frames get rendered before recalculating these drivers. A simple solution for it would be to force one more frame update before rendering it.

Comment: Does this happen if you save the animation as individual png files? If it's ok, you could then reassemble it from the png files in the video sequencer and save in the video format you need.

Comment: @JohnEason I always save it as png files. I don't see how it could make a difference anyway, Blender wouldn't just start updating frames more times before starting a render only because I changed the way it's saved.

Comment: Did you try writing a python script? Which simply renders still images in a loop for all frames?

Comment: @Chris No, I did not, I don't know python. Anyway, wouldn't that just be the same? Unless some additional frame update is coded in.